# How to count search results in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

How to find in the text file using Vim how many times specific word repeats.

For example, I want to see how many times word "name" repeats in the code:

```
"collection": "animals",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "id",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "field": "age",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "field": "origin",
        "name": ""
      }
```

Result - 3

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can count the number of matches using the `n` flag in the substitute command. Use the following to show number of times that `some-word` matches text in current buffer:

```
:%s/some-word//gn
```

You can read all the details on the [vim tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern)

Comment: for read-only buffers one has to do the extra step of `:set modifiable`

Answer (score 51):

Nowadays (as of Vim [8.1.1270](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1270)) you can use:

```
set shortmess-=S
```

to enable a count of `[x/y]` showing in the bottom right corner every time you do a `/` or `?` search.

[image: native search count]

[**Relevant section from the Vim help**](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shortmess%27)

Note that if the search finds more than 99 results, Vim unfortunately just shows `[x/>99]`:

[image: native search count over 99]

For this reason, I personally use the [google/vim-searchindex](https://github.com/google/vim-searchindex) plugin, which works for any amount of results:

[image: vim-search-index search count]

(By default the plugin is limited to files with “only” less than one million lines; this can be adjusted with `let g:searchindex_line_limit=2000000`.)

Comment: What does `-` do?

Comment: It removes the S flag from the setting.

Comment: @ruohola Which colorscheme are you using?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8 with `set background=dark` and `colorscheme solarized8`.

Comment: @ruohola Thanks. I think I used that once, but it did not look that great using Terminal.app on macOS

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Not sure what's happening there. I'm using iTerm2 and have activated solarized colors from `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Color Presets -> Solarized Dark`

Comment: Isn't a configuration to make Vim show more characters for  [x/>99] ?

Comment: @aemonge Unfortunately it's simply hardcoded: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/bc67e5a0a494f5fc48e872d747371e31a782d171/src/search.c#L40

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands.

1. Multiple matches per line

```
:%s/pattern//ng
```

`g` stands for global, it will match multiple occurrences per line.

*Outputs* are shown as

```
13 matches on 10 lines
```

2. Line matches

```
:%s/pattern//n
```

*Outputs* are shown as

```
10 matches on 10 lines
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a count word function that you cand use in a number of ways

```
fun! CountWordFunction()
    try
        let l:win_view = winsaveview()
        exec "%s/" . expand("<cword>") . "//gn"
    finally
        call winrestview(l:win_view)
    endtry
endfun
command! -nargs=0 CountWord :call CountWordFunction()
```

So, you can map it:

```
nnoremap <F3> :CountWord<CR>
```

Even mouse double click...

```
" When double click a word vim will hightlight all other ocurences
" see CountWordFunction()
" [I shows lines with word under the cursor
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>
nnoremap <Leader>* :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

My [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) would print the following output (with the cursor on the first match, and the `<A-m>` mapping or `:SearchPosition name` command):

```
On sole match in this line, 2 in following lines within 5,13 for /\<name\>/
```

It builds on the other solutions given here, and was expressly written for obtaining such statistics easily.